# Firefox not allowing selection on two text input at same time

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, textselection

I have two basic text input in an HTML page, if none of them is in focus and I press CTR+A or CMD+A shortcut then the content of both text input is not getting selected on firefox, working fine on chrome

```
<div>
<input type="text" onkeydown="myFunction(event)" value="test">
<input type="text" value="test1">
</div>
```

Even selection API is not wokring as expected on firefox i.e it is not selecting two text box simultaneously.
I have created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hkurra/15tL9o3g/7/) 
to explain the problem. I need to select all text input content under particular parent node(div in my case), this fiddle is working fine as expected on both chrome and safari but not firefox,

I have tried both range API and selection API as follow

```
window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(event.target.parentNode);
```

or

```
let range = document.createRange();

range.setStart(event.target.parentNode, 0);
range.setEnd(event.target.parentNode, 1);

window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes Firefox doesn't allow selection of input's content. That's a security measure I guess.

You can workaround that issue by setting the `textContent` property of your inputs, this way, you'll be able to select and copy their content even in Firefox.

I do this in the `selectionchange` event, but you are free to call it whenever is the best for your case.

```js
document.onselectionchange = e => {
  console.log(e);
  // every time the selection changes
  document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(el => {
    // except when we are the one in focus
    if(document.activeElement === el) return;
    // update each <input>'s textContent property
    el.textContent = el.value;
  })
}
```

```html
<p>Try to select all (ctrl+A) the page and copy to clipboard (ctrl+C)</p>

<div>
  <input type="text" value="test">
  <input type="text" value="test1">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I have tested your solution it is working fine if we need default select all & copy behavior, but your solution does not force Firefox to select text in text input field, unlike chrome and safari, even with Selection API  firefox is behaving in similar fashion i.e it is making a selection behind the scene in model somewhere which I can access through selection API.
with your solution, I don't need to handle select all separately, but even with that copy is not working smoothly on safari, I am going to handle all event by myself, will keep you posted.
Thanks Again